# display predicted values for initial data using auto.arima in R

Tags: r, time-series, lapply, arima

Let's work with this data sample

```
timeseries<-structure(list(Data = structure(c(10L, 14L, 18L, 22L, 26L, 29L, 
32L, 35L, 38L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 11L, 15L, 19L, 23L, 27L, 30L, 33L, 
36L, 39L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 24L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 
40L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 25L), .Label = c("01.01.2018", 
"01.01.2019", "01.01.2020", "01.02.2018", "01.02.2019", "01.02.2020", 
"01.03.2018", "01.03.2019", "01.03.2020", "01.04.2017", "01.04.2018", 
"01.04.2019", "01.04.2020", "01.05.2017", "01.05.2018", "01.05.2019", 
"01.05.2020", "01.06.2017", "01.06.2018", "01.06.2019", "01.06.2020", 
"01.07.2017", "01.07.2018", "01.07.2019", "01.07.2020", "01.08.2017", 
"01.08.2018", "01.08.2019", "01.09.2017", "01.09.2018", "01.09.2019", 
"01.10.2017", "01.10.2018", "01.10.2019", "01.11.2017", "01.11.2018", 
"01.11.2019", "01.12.2017", "01.12.2018", "01.12.2019"), class = "factor"), 
    client = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("Horns", "Kornev"), class = "factor"), stuff = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("chickens", 
    "hooves", "Oysters"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(374L, 
    12L, 120L, 242L, 227L, 268L, 280L, 419L, 12L, 172L, 336L, 
    117L, 108L, 150L, 90L, 117L, 116L, 146L, 120L, 211L, 213L, 
    67L, 146L, 118L, 152L, 122L, 201L, 497L, 522L, 65L, 268L, 
    441L, 247L, 348L, 445L, 477L, 62L, 226L, 476L, 306L)), .Names = c("Data", 
"client", "stuff", "Sales"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

I want to perform forecast using auto.arima by group

```
# first the grouping variable
timeseries$group <- paste0(timeseries$client,timeseries$stuff)

# now the list
listed <- split(timeseries,timeseries$group)

library("forecast")
library("lubridate")

listed_ts <- lapply(listed,
                    function(x) ts(x[["Sales"]], start = start = c(2017, 1), frequency = 12)  ) 

listed_ts

listed_arima <- lapply(listed_ts,function(x) auto.arima(x) )
#Now the forecast for each arima:
listed_forecast <- lapply(listed_arima,function(x) forecast(x,2) )
listed_forecast
do.call(rbind,listed_forecast)
```

If i do so i get forecast on future, but i want see, what auto.arima model predicts for initial value from my example.
To be more clear.
 In my example `Sales` for 01.04.2017 Horns chickens=374. Right? How can I see what value the auto.arima model predicted for this date and another dates from example data.

So output
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those values are known as *fitted* values and they can be obtained with the function `fitted` as follows:

```
lapply(listed_arima, fitted)
# $Hornschickens
#          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov
# 2017 223.8182 223.8182 223.8182 223.8182 223.8182 223.8182 223.8182 223.8182 223.8182 223.8182 223.8182
#
# $Hornshooves
#           Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
# 2017 336.9231 336.9231 336.9231 336.9231 336.9231 336.9231 336.9231 336.9231 336.9231 336.9231 336.9231 336.9231
# 2018 336.9231                                                                                                   
#
# $KornevOysters
#          Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec
# 2017 137.125 137.125 137.125 137.125 137.125 137.125 137.125 137.125 137.125 137.125 137.125 137.125
# 2018 137.125 137.125 137.125 137.125
```

In this case results are not very interesting as all the fitted models are ARIMA(0,0,0) - white noise.

---

As a side comment, note that the solution is equivalent to

```
lapply(listed_arima, function(x) fitted(x))
```

For the same reason you may also use

```
listed_arima <- lapply(listed_ts, auto.arima)
```