# how to predict in-sample using auto.arima?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Consider this simple example

```
> WWWusage %>% as_tibble() %>% head()
# A tibble: 6 x 1
      x
  <dbl>
1    88
2    84
3    85
4    85
5    84
6    85
```

I know I can fit a `ARIMA` model using the `forecast` package. This is easy.

```
> fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
> fit
Series: WWWusage 
ARIMA(1,1,1) 

Coefficients:
         ar1     ma1
      0.6504  0.5256
s.e.  0.0842  0.0896

sigma^2 estimated as 9.995:  log likelihood=-254.15
AIC=514.3   AICc=514.55   BIC=522.08
```

The problem is that I would like to predict the one-step ahead forecast in my training sample. That is, how can I have a column `prediction` in my original data which contains the predictions from `fit`?

Using `forecast` will only return the forecasts for obs. `101` to `110` (out-of-sample).

```
> forecast(fit)
    Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
101       218.8805 214.8288 222.9322 212.6840 225.0770
102       218.1524 208.4496 227.8552 203.3133 232.9915
```

I want all the previous (in-sample) forecasts as well (using the same parameters). Like doing `broom:augment()` with `lm`.

How can I do that here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for the ARIMA-predicted values for each observation in your data set?

Comment: yes correct, this is what I want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display predicted values for initial data using auto.arima in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924851/display-predicted-values-for-initial-data-using-auto-arima-in-r)

Comment: @hmhensen thanks. but do you know how to properly align the fitted values with the data then? I would like the predictions to be in my original tibble

Comment: here we obviously lose one obs when we fit the arma. how can I get back the prediction to the tibble  `WWWusage %>% as_tibble()`

Comment: thanks. do you mind posting this as a solution? also, doing `df$fitted` as you suggest will generate a crazy column name. how can I just have `fitted` in the tibble instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the solution below.

```
df <- WWWusage %>% as_tibble()
fit <- auto.arima(df)
df$fitted <- fitted(fit)
```

Since you're using `dplyr`, for the last step, you can also do:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(fitted = fitted(fit))
```

If you're wondering why the fitted values line up exactly with the original observations, you can read the `forecast` package documentation. Rob Hyndman developed the package and it's quite sophisticated. He uses backcasts and forecasts of a series' moving averages to fill in the missing information.

For more explanation, see his online book on forecasting at https://otexts.com/fpp2/ and the documentation for the `forecast` at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf.

Comment: it is indeed surprising that the first observation in the data has a prediction. do you know how to disable that back-forecasting?

Comment: I don't think it can be, but I've never tried so I can't say for sure.